# Searching Pattern after a specific pattern in bash script

Tags: bash, shell, awk

i have to search 100 files of following format.

```
<dependencies>
<a1 build="true">
<a2 build="false">
<a3 build="false">
<deployments>
<a1 build="false">
<a2 build="true">
<a3 build="false">
```

I have to find all files who have atleast 1 deployment where build="true". The problem is how should i start the search after the string deployment so that dependencies where build="true" doesnot come into search.

Comment: Is that the total content of each file?

Answer (score 0):

```
awk 'FNR == 0 { dep = 0; }
     /<deployments>/ { dep = 1; }
     /build="true"/ && dep { print FILENAME; nextfile; }' file1 file2 ...
```

Comment: That should be `{ print FILENAME; dep=0; nextfile; }` , no?

Comment: Actually, I think my suggestion is not complete either, since if the first file has no builds that are true the dep remains 1 for the second file.. So I think `dep` should be set to 0 in a `FNR==1{ }` condition,